# Custom email not creating with default Header and footer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, header, footer

I visited and tried all related solutions available on stack exchange so decided to add my question too as issue is not resolved.

**Function is:**

```
  public function sendEmail()
    {
        $email="myEmail@gmail.com";
        $name="Ajwad";
        $subject="test";
        $message="msg";
        $templateVars = array(
            'store' => $this->storeManager->getStore(),
            'customer_name' =>$name,
            'email' => $email,
            'subject'   => $subject,
            'message'   => $message
        );
        try {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            $error = false;
            $sender = [
                'name' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($name),
                'email' => $this->escaper->escapeHtml($email),
            ];
        $to = array('myEmail@gmail.com');
        //$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('email_demo_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($to)
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->debug($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**In etc/email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
<template id="email_demo_template" label="This is email demo" file="email_demo_template.html" type="html" module="Vendor_ModuleName" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**In view/frontend/email/email_demo_template.html**

```
<!--@subject Customer Inquiry @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
<!--@vars {
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->
{Error in template processing}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello"}},</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                    Name: {{var customer_name}}
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                    Subject: {{var subject}}
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                Message: {{var message}}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                                <center>
                                    <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                        <strong>{{trans "Thank you"}}</strong>
                                    </p>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {Error in template processing}
```

It sends email as:

[image]

but I want to get Header and footer in email for that I added

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}} <!-- header -->
<!-- custom table content--->
{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}} <!-- footer -->
```

**As**

```
<!--@subject Customer Inquiry @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
<!--@vars {
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/footer_template\"":"Email Footer Template",
"template config_path=\"design\/email\/header_template\"":"Email Header Template"
} @-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                    <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top">
                                <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello"}},</h1>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                    Name: {{var customer_name}}
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                    Subject: {{var subject}}
                                                </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:12px;padding:7px 9px 9px 9px;border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
                                                Message: {{var message}}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA;text-align:center;">
                                <center>
                                    <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                        <strong>{{trans "Thank you"}}</strong>
                                    </p>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

But doing this email is not created (no response). When I set area to ADMINHTML and created template file at view/adminhtml/eamil/email_demo_template.html including header and footer tag email is created but with this error:

[image]

Please guide towards solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using magento default store id i.e. 0

Please try to change store code like this and try

```
$transport = $this->transportBuilder
            ->setTemplateIdentifier('email_demo_template')
            ->setTemplateOptions(
                [
                    'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                    'store' => 1, /* just add 1 for testing if work change dynamically*/ 
                ]
            )
```

You can override your header and footer template like this

```
    app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/header.html
    app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Email/email/footer.html
```

Comment: with 'store' => 1 email is creating without header and footer tag, but with header and footer tag no response

Comment: check header footer template is exists in you theme or parent theme

Comment: how can I check header and footer ? if I go to Marketing->Email Templates and look at the preview the email looks fine

Comment: check it is present in your theme or parent theme if not create or copy file in your theme